# What is the recommended way to factor iOS UI initialization?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uikit

In an iOS view controller I typically have code like:

```c
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    // [several lines of code to configure the view]
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView]
}
```

This tends to get cluttered so I add a helper method (e.g. `createScrollView`) to alloc, init, and configure the view. Is this an established pattern for building views and is there a convention for naming the helper methods? One thing I noticed is that the name `initScrollView` is not allowed because of ARC.

Comment: One very common pattern for building views is with interface builder. I assume that it does not fit your needs, though, correct?

Comment: Best practice is to do as much of the UI set up as possible on the Storyboard and as little as possible in code, because, as you said: clutter.  However, when I do have to do some UI set up, I'll just do as you suggested, with a method such as `createScrollView` that does everything I need to do, and just call that method from `viewDidLoad` or somewhere that makes sense.

Comment: I'm building my views programmatically mainly to learn and go beyond what the Interface Builder provides.

Comment: You can still do a lot of it in the interface builder and then just make tweaks in code.  Five minutes of twiddling around in the interface builder can save several lines of code and make your code more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the pattern I follow:

In `init` / `initWithFrame:` create your objects, and set any properties which will never change during the life of this controller:

```
- (instancetype) init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        _textField = [UITextField new];
        _textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
    }

    return self;
}
```

If you want to separate these out into methods like `createTextFields`, etc., that's fine, although it's easier to debug if you can see a list of everything instantiated in one place.

In `viewDidLoad`, set up the view hierarchy:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [self.view addSubview:self.textField];
}
```

In `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, set the frames (if you're not using auto-layout):

```
- (void) viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    self.textField.frame = CGRectMake(10, 44, 320, 50);
}
```

This approach will set you up for success handling view resizing and rotation events.

Comment: Is there an advantage to initializing the subviews in -init as opposed to -loadView?